# Heat Exchange Between Two Blocks

Tags: thermodynamics

One question that was posed to me was this: if two otherwise identical blocks are at $100$ and $0$ degrees Celsius, and for clarity the hot block is red and the cold block is blue, what is the maximum difference in temperature between the initially cold block and the initially warm block? The catch is you can cut pieces and recombine pieces, but at the end all the blue pieces and red pieces must be back in their original configuration.

Initially, my thought process was that the maximum difference must be $0$, since by combining the entirety of both blocks together, you get that each block reaches an equilibrium of $50$ degrees Celsius, which means the difference is $0$.

However, what if you were to combine an infinitesimally small piece of blue with the entirety of the red block, the new temperature would become $$T_{n+1}=\lim_{\delta b\to0}(T_n\times\frac{\delta b}{\delta b+r})$$

and with $N$ blue pieces, the final temperature would be
$$T_{final} = \lim_{\delta b\to0} T_{initial} \times (\frac{r}{\delta b+r})^N$$

If we defined N such that it would be the number of elements of mass $\delta b$ required to hit the entirety of mass $b$, then we could rewrite the limit as
$$T_{final} = \lim_{\delta b\to0} T_{initial} \times (\frac{r}{\delta b+r})^{\frac{b}{\delta b}}$$

which should become $T_{initial}/e$. Why is this the case? Does this violate the second law of thermodynamics? If yes, what did I do wrong?

Comment: There seems to be something missing from the problem. What processes can be done to the blocks besides cutting them? Why isn't the maximum difference $100^{\circ}C$? Can you provide the problem as it was originally stated?

Comment: No matter how you connect the two blocks, they will eventually reach steady state. Hence at the junction, the two surfaces will have the same temperature.

Comment: The linked question *Switching temperature of two objects* is a different question which asks if the temperatures of A and B can be switched.